# I am not able to interpret the following one line code

Tags: arrays, scala

The below code is written in scala,

```
val Array(f, t) = readLine().trim().split(" +").map(_.toInt)
```

I am not able to comprehend `val Array(f, t)`.

To me, `Array` is class. Due to that, We can only create the object and with that object, we can access the function of the class. Or else We can access the static methods of the Array class without creating an object for it.

-- scala

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val n = readInt
    val m = readInt
    val f = Array.ofDim[Int](100000)
    Arrays.fill(f, -1)
    for (e <- 1 to m) {
        val Array(f, t) = readLine().trim().split(" +").map(_.toInt)
        // Code continues
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is called pattern matching (for example you can check [this](https://www.protechtraining.com/blog/post/an-introduction-to-pattern-matching-in-scala-842) at **Extractors**). The code you mentioned means that please assign the first (index `0`) value in the array resulting to `f`, assign the second (index `1`) element to `t` and there should not be more or less values in the array. Both `f` and `t` are fresh variables.

You also mentioned the confusion with the `val Array(...)` syntax. It translates to the following method: [`scala.Array.unapplySeq[T](x:Array[T])`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#unapplySeq[T](x:Array[T]):Option[IndexedSeq[T]])